# How do I get these ports enabled?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata, pci-express, disk-controller

I have a qNine 6 port data pcie controller card that will not enable ports 5 and 6. Or rather the card at boot does not display the HDDs attached. The card, however, does indicate there is some thing there.

I have done the following:

1. Replaced the data and power cables. Reseated the cables.
2. Tried different drives.
3. Tried different cards.
4. Updated drivers in windows.

This appears to be a common problem with this card.

Is there a BIOS setting on the card that needs to be enabled?

Do I need to update the f/w on the card? If so, how?

There is nothing on the disk that came with it and I have not been able to find a url for additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that card has a BIOS you can configure.

Based on some photos on Google this appears to be based on an AS-Media 1062 SATA controller and 2 ASM 1093 SATA port-expander chips.
It is very unlikely that a low-cost manufacturer like qNine made any serious changes to the standard AS-Media reference design. So it ought to work with the normal AS-Media drivers for the ASM-1062 which you can easily find via Google.
(AS-Media doesn't offer them directly as they don't do business with end-users.)

The other possibility is that one of the two port-expander chips on the card is faulty.
From the photos I would hazard a guess (based on the visible PCB traces) that ports 5 and 6 are the lower 2 ports on the card (closest to the motherboard) and connected to the 2nd ASM1092. The upper 4 ports all connect to the first ASM1092.

Last but not least... These cards appear to be not the most stable product on the market judging from the amount of Google hits about stability issues, but you already had discovered that yourself. It could be there isn't a solution and you may have to live with the problem.

Comment: Yeah,... I did some research into the card and the controllers. It only has 2 controllers on it and they are definitely 2 ports each. I’ve since returned both cards and had amazon pull th3 cards due to false advertising.

Comment: @JohnSchultz So they just soldered 2 dummy ports on the card? I've seen some crazy stuff, including Chinese clones of reputable chips, that were sold as originals, but didn't fully implement all features. But selling a 4-port device as a 6-port... That is a new one. Possible that qNine didn't even now. Could be they just bought a couple of shipping containers of these cards somewhere in Asia, rebranded the boxes and sold them, without actually testing them. (Or just tested a few from the first batch, but the manufacturer changed the later batches.)

Comment: Yup! I tried two completely different cards from the same vendor (well different lot numbers that is), and the same issue crap came to the surface as beforehand..

The solution for me was to get a refund and get a completely different card altogether, I purchased a PCIe x4 card that actually works BEAUTIFULLY!

The ASIN is: B07S8CB398

Comment: Glad to hear you involved Amazon in this. Many people can’t be bothered. Leaving those cowboys free to rip off more unsuspecting customers.

Comment: Here is the really sad part, the card shows six connected devices (indicators on the card that is), a