# Do cheap SATA expansion cards work?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, expansion-cards

I work in a soft-and hardware company. We started cleaning up and I found about 16 harddrives that are together about 4.5TB. I want to use them all and make a sort of file server in my home. But I found out SATA expansion cards are quite expensive so I found one that is really [cheap](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/33009101068.html?scm=1007.22893.125781.0&pvid=e14062c1-8be8-4edd-9481-cdf0b4cd0dd2&onelink_thrd=0.015&onelink_page_from=ITEM_DETAIL&onelink_item_to=33009101068&onelink_duration=1.222436&onelink_status=noneresult&onelink_item_from=33009101068&onelink_page_to=ITEM_DETAIL&af=318847&afref=https%253A%252F%252Fbe.redbrain.shop%252F&cn=19676&cv=735481&dp=735481%253A%253A318847%253A%253AQ2p3S0NBaUFfX0h2QlJBQ0Vpd0FiVml1VTRMRm9Jd0d5UnE5R1NTaUlkLVVCT1ZqY1VpSDBJd280OU1jRkprcy1wTmx2X3dPakJLN1lob0M3ejBRQXZEX0J3RQ%253A%253A%253A%253A1576874631&aff_platform=aaf&cpt=1576874631715&sk=YfmMrZfMJ&aff_trace_key=ae41747df402423d90539d2230aff678-1576874631715-03463-YfmMrZfMJ&terminal_id=30c0e54e408b4cf0928ad9999526046e) but will it properly work? Are there negatives?

Comment: Have you consider the power consumption? And probably you will need to create kind of RAID which will consume processor power.....

Comment: Marvell chips are very good. You are better off to buy a cheap jbod (just a bunch of drives) enclosure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't really make sense on several levels...

In order to get 16 of these drives working in a single computer you need 3 or 4 of these PICe cards in order to get enough SATA ports (assuming you also can use some on the motherboard itself). Even real cheap (and hoping you don't get a Chinese knockoff piece of crap) that is still about $50.
No normal PC case has space for 16 drives. So you will need to get very creative to fit everything together. Cooling is going to be an issue. Not to mention the noise and vibration.
You are also going to need a serious power-supply and a lot of power-cables/splitters to power it all.

And all of that for 16 old, relatively small capacity, used drives. And you have no idea how much wear and abuse these drives have already suffered in their lifetime.

And setting up software RAID over that many drives is going to really load your CPU.

A brand new 6 TB SATA drive will set you back about $80-$100. That makes a lot more sense to me.

Comment: I know, I just want to do it as a sort of project, I have anything sorted out but the expansion card, I would need 2, I have 4 extra SATA ports on my card. I know enough about servers and hard drives.

Comment: @emile One off those kind of projects... Well, if you only need 2 of them and have everythign else sorted... You could take a chance on those SATA expanders. But check out this other question first: https://superuser.com/questions/1493441/how-do-i-get-these-ports-enabled